# Archive/table not looking as it's supposed to

Tags: php, css, archive

https://s27.postimg.org/niua66jqr/archive.jpg

I had my table as it is in the right image, but I had to add some code to the `archive.php` file. I didn't modify any of the archive table code, just added a header and footer. Now, it looks like the image on the left. Is there something in the `style.css` file that I can change (like `display:`  ?) or modify some of the original archive code?

```
<div class="archive-container">

    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var domainroot="sitetitle.com"
            function Gsitesearch(curobj){
                curobj.q.value="site:"+domainroot+" "+curobj.qfront.value
                }

        </script>


        <form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" onSubmit="Gsitesearch(this)">

            <p class="search">Search:<br />
            <input name="q" type="hidden" class="texta" />
            <input name="qfront" type="text" style="width: 186px; text-size: 12px; height: 14px;" /> </p>

        </form>


        <table id=arc>
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, MONTH(post_date) as `month`, DAYOFMONTH(post_date) as `dayofmonth`, ID, post_name, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'article' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC";
            $key = md5($query);
            $cache = wp_cache_get( 'mp_archives' , 'general');
            if ( !isset( $cache[ $key ] ) ) {
              $arcresults = $wpdb->get_results($query);
              $cache[ $key ] = $arcresults;
              wp_cache_add( 'mp_archives', $cache, 'general' );
            } else {
              $arcresults = $cache[ $key ];
            }
            if ($arcresults) {
              $last_year = 0;
              $last_month = 0;
              foreach ( $arcresults as $arcresult ) {
                $year = $arcresult->year;
                $month = $arcresult->month;
                if ($year != $last_year) {
                  $last_year = $year;
                  $last_month = 0;
            ?>
            <tr class=year><th><br /><br /><?php echo $arcresult->year; ?></th></tr>
                <?php
                    }
                    if ($month != $last_month) {
                      $last_month = $month;
                ?>
            <tr class=archive><th><?php echo $wp_locale->get_month($arcresult->month); ?></th><td></td></tr>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            <tr class=archive>
                <th><?php echo $arcresult->dayofmonth; ?></th>
                <td id=p<?php echo $arcresult->ID; ?>>
                    <a href="/<?php echo $arcresult->post_name; ?>">
                    <?php echo strip_tags(apply_filters('the_title', $arcresult->post_title)); ?></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
              }
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>  <!-- /end .container -->
```

Comment: Something that might be a help is to do a diff on the two versions and see if anything unexpected what deleted or added.

Comment: The approach I would take is to make a copy of what you added, then revert the files back to what they were and confirm that it works again as expected.

Then slowly add sections of your new code and check the layout afterwards, to isolate which part of your new code is causing the problem.

Comment: `<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
 <head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>sitetitle.com</title>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
 </head>`

Comment: I did, it was what was at the very top, which also made the `style.css` work. I think there might be something in the style file to modify. Changing the display to `display: table-column` did it, but with the width very small (so it had to go to the next line).